# vb.net with google.apis.calendar.v3 can read but cannot create new event (no error)

Tags: vb.net

already use oauth 2 to allow manage account
i can read or query events, but cannot create new events

tried something like:
a = service.Events.Insert(myevent, "primary")
or 
use quick insert

code got executed with no error, but nothing happened